# Jmeter Rest API Performance Testing - POST data is not working in replay

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am very new to Performance Testing and Jmeter

This is my POST data sending as request
POST data:

```
[{"state":"COMPLETED","taskId":"2007","properties":[{"value":"2018-07-25T16:44:40.121Z","id":"deliveryDate"}]}]
```

Response:

```
{"id":null,"message":"Error in 2007: Cannot find task with id 2007;","status":"BAD_REQUEST"}
```

But when i recorded the script below is the response for the above POST data (which is correct)

```
[{"filingDetailsId":24,"filingStatus":"ACTIVE","fund":{"fundId":24,"name":"AG Mortgage Value Partners Master Fund, L.P.","shortCode":"MVPM"},"task":{"taskId":"9535","state":"ACTIVE","description":"The date the data was provided by the admin.","taskSubType":"MASTER","assignee":"[]","properties":[{"id":"deliveryDate","name":"Admin Actual Delivery Date","type":{"name":"date"},"value":"False","required":true,"writable":true,"readable":true}]},"refFundId":101,"reportId":0},]
```

Why does my replay fail? Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have enough details to come up with a 100% correct answer so I'll go for a "blind shot"

If your test scenario assumes a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operation like:

1. Create a task
2. The task goes through some workflow
3. The task is marked as completed or is deleted

Then this is not something you can record and replay without implementing so called [**correlation**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) - the process of extracting dynamic parameters from previous request and passing them to next one.

So you need to do some extra work on your recorded test and make it look like:

- HTTP Request to create a task

  - [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to extract the task ID and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- HTTP Request to mark the task as completed - replace `2007` with the value of `taskId` from the previous request. You might also want to replace `2018-07-25T16:44:40.121Z` with current timestamp which you can obtain via [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function as otherwise your requests will be in the past and your application might have an internal check to prevent potentially fraudulent behaviour.